# Error occurred during when im exporting the gridview data to pdf in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

If I do `onClick` of a button(`btnConverttoPDF`) in some form it will
 create PDF with all the content inside the form..

It's working fine locally.. But when the application is deployed in server then 
it's raising an error.. as follows

> "No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it 127.0.0.15:55374"   WebException: unable to connect to the
>   remove server   and mentioning the path of the file like
>   E:\Main\OnlineSite\OnlineBanking\ClosingBalance.aspx.cs

Just now I found the issue..

the Image control is causing an issue.. during

htmlparser.Parse(sr);

Here is the Code which I've tried

```
protected void btnconvert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
{
using (HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
{
//To Export all pages
grdLast10trans.AllowPaging = false;
BindGrid();  //Calling a Function, here im adding the data to the Datasource and diplaying in Grid
content.RenderControl(hw);
StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A3, 10f, 10f, 10f, 10f);
HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);

PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
pdfDoc.Open();
//pdfDoc.NewPage(); 
htmlparser.Parse(sr); //Here it's causing error b'coz of image contol
pdfDoc.Close();
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.pdf");
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Write(pdfDoc); 
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
}
}
}
```

Comment: is that IP address the correct address for whatever service you are calling?

Comment: <asp:image id="image1" imageurl="http://localhost/OnlineBanking/img/bank_logo.PNG" runat="server"></asp:image> This is causing the probe.. How can i set the URL to make it workable at server